# It says the call is ambiguous, but there is only one namespace

Tags: c#, namespaces, extension-methods

I'm porting some code to .NET Standard 2.1, and now I get an error doing this:

tmpQuote.SpecialCosts.RemoveAll(cqMainCost => dsSpecialCosts.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Any(row => cqMainCost.Name == row.Field("CostName")));

it fails on the AsEnumerable()

The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Data.DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable(System.Data.DataTable)' and 'System.Data.DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable(System.Data.DataTable)'

Usually there is ambiguity between the same method name, but in two different namespaces.

Here there is ambiguity between the same method name, in the same namespace?

The project is referencing the nuget package: System.Data.DataSetExtensions
And the project is also referencing other projects that in turn reference the same nuget package.

But that is a common thing to do, and have never caused this problem for me.

UPDATE:  Found this: https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/1622

This made me look closer at other projects being referenced, and they are 2.0 not 2.1
Changing my project to 2.0 solved the issue.

Comment: What is the code and the using clauses?

Comment: This can happen if you reference two Dlls that define the same extension method. For example while you can reference both the Aspnet Appinsights *and* the Worker Service app insights package, the second you attempt to use one of the extension methods you get an error similar to the above (but for AI, of course) and it's because both packages have a class called XxxExtensions in the same namespace with the same methods and signatures. The compiler has no way to disambiguate and thus the problem. You'd need assembly aliases which VS doesn't support. You are likely hitting a similar issue.

Comment: The point of all that is to say, review the packages you are referencing (directly and transitively) and ensure you don't have one that is unnecessary.

Comment: What you write makes sense.  I was hoping for an less brute force method, since this insane class have no less than 55 "using xyz"s ( it is 18k lines).  It would be nice if I could see what 2 sources/dlls/references that where colliding

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that it was a net standard 2.1 project, referencing other net standard 2.0 projects.  And the DataSetExtensions is not identical in 2.0 and 2.1

Changing the project to 2.0 solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

It is actually just part of netstandard2.1 so you can remove the package reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions and then you can stay with netstandard2.1 instead of reverting to 2.0 see: https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/1622